# Cannot display footer at the bottom of the page correctly - CSS Only "Sticky" footer

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML, Body and Main html tags set to `position: fixed;`, with the Main tag also set to `overflow: scroll;`. This has gave me my desired effect without having to use javascript, of having a scrollable main div.

Now i have inputted the Footer tag and set the height and width, Yet it overlaps the `Main` Div.I have tried every possible position attribute to get it to display properly and stick to the bottom of the page underneath the main content and for it to scroll up, when the last div is scrolled. But to no avail, I have tried numerous things, changing the positions, width, and height, I have googled for similar issues and looked at SO, but i cannot find anything, It may perhaps be my search terms, yet i still cannot figure it out.

Ultimately i want it to appear at the bottom of the `Main` div once that has finished scrolling.

I do not want to place the `footer` tag inside the `main` tag as this would be semantically incorrect with HTML5, although yes it would work.

```css
html, body {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
body {
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/wallpaper.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom center;
}
/* The CSS in this Section is for the Page Header */
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #828485;
}
.imgwrap {
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 height: 150px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 }
.gradient {
 top: 100px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#828485 0%, #fff 100%);
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
/* End of Page Header */
/* Main Content */
main {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 66%;
 display: block;
 overflow: scroll;
}
main::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
#over {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 800px;
 color: #fff;
}
.split {
 background-color: rgba(147,151,153,0.6);
 color: rgb(237,36,62);
 height: 350px;
}
#activity {
 height: 800px;
}
#servers {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 800px;
}
/* End of Main */
/* Start of footer */
footer {
  position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #828485; 
}
```

```html
<header>
<img src="images/Banners/exile.png" alt="exile logo" class="imgwrap">
<div class="gradient"></div
</header>
  <!-- End of Page Head, Start of Main Content -->
<main id="start">
<section id="over"> 
<img src="images/backgrounds/exile-main1.png" alt="x-cessive background">
<article class="para">
<h3> Some Header </h3> 
</article>
</section>
<section class="split">
<h2>"A second Header"</h2>
</section>
<section id="activity">
<img src="images/backgrounds/activity.png" alt="x-cessive-activity">
<h2> Another Header </h2>
<article class="para1"></article>
</section>
<section class="split">
<h2>"Yet another header"</h2>
</section>
<section id="servers">
<img src="images/backgrounds/server.png" alt="x-cessive Servers"/>
<h2>How many headers</h2>
<article class="para">
<h3>This is too many headers now</h3><br/>
<h3>Last one I promise</h3> 
</article>
</section>
</main>
<!-- end of main content -->
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  Contact an Admin.
</footer>
```

Comment: I have updated the codepen, so you can see abit better of what i want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

See I'm unable to understand what you really want us to help you with... And I can see that you are not using any framework to build the page. But I'll highly recommend you to use any CSS framework so that you may not have to suffer from such problems. I'm listing some of the popular frameworks.
Some frameworks here-

Bootstrap, MaterializeCSS, Bootstrap with material

So the problem I see in your code is regarding the footer overflowing content that can be easily resolved by using such frameworks.

Comment: As much as frameworks help, they never really help you learn the code. I am trying to get the footer at the bottom of the page to only show when i have scrolled to the bottom of the main content.

Comment: At least frameworks can save your time a lot. Anyways I'm looking into your code again.

Comment: Cheers, I have been up all night looking at javascript and now i'm so tired i cant think. The height from the Main div is not being picked up properly, otherwise it would work okay

Answer (score 0):

I am also a bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve.

I removed `position:fixed;` from the footer and it snapped to the bottom revealing the main content with the tabs (Home, Activity, Servers, Members) and stopped the footer overlapping.

Comment: No, That doesn't work, Everything from my main content is scrollable, on a fixed position div, The footer overlaps this, Removing p;osition: fixed, puts it behind the Main div but under the Head section section.

Comment: removing position:fixed snaps it under the head section, under the main content, so when you scroll the transparent parts you can see the footer at the bottom of the header, I can get it to stick at the bottom, but then it overlaps the main content, and i need it to "appear" when the the user scrolls to the bottom of the servers div.